# MSVS C# fastest way to remove try-catch blocks?

Tags: try-catch

I took over an incomplete project and to my utter disbelieve, every single function is wrapped with try-catch statements in this same format:

```
try
{
   // work work.
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ...);
}
```

As I search SO for a method to quickly remove all these try-catch blocks, I find that people are actually looking for method to automatically wrap their functions with try-catch! hmmm... Is that good programming practice at all? Is there is method to remove all blocks instead so that it makes debugging easier and allows me to really solve the exceptions?

Comment: I had to do this once... my solution was an 8 hour strech of copy/paste 900+ times to add {throw;} to the end of all of them and retest the entire thing. Fun times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the option here:

```
Debug -> Exceptions -> CLR Exceptions -> Check the "Thrown" checkbox.
```

This causes the compiler to break whenever an exception is thrown, before checking any `catch` blocks.

Comment: +1 - Note that this only means you will catch exceptions in the debugger rather than them being suppressed by the program - it doesn't "permanently" disable the exception handling.

Comment: This is actually really helpful. Thanks! Yea, but would also like to disable as Jason said.

Answer (score 3):

This is a horrible programming practice.  I once saw this as a bug mess up someone's database.

It is my firm opinion you are better off letting your program die a fiery death than mindlessly continue on in an unknown state.

I would do a find and replace on  `MessageBox.Show(ex`   with `throw //MessageBox.Show(ex`  and replace them all.  You will have to manually find the ones that should really be there and put them back.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio's Regex search is pretty powerful, however it is a bit tricky to use, here is something that you might find useful in searching for your above code: (Note in the find dialog box, in the Options section choose "Use: Regular Expressions")

Will find your bad catches:

> catch.*\n+:b+{[.:b\n]*MessageBox.*[.:b\n]*}

If you want to do a straight replace with a throw:

> catch\n{\nthrow;\n}

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a solution to this for VB.NET.

Replace this:

`\s(?<!End )Try((.|\r\n)+?)Catch(.|\r\n)+?(Finally((.|\r\n)+?)End Try|End Try)`

...with this:

`$1$5`

It will remove the entire try/catch block while leaving behind only what was in the try and finally blocks.  It doesn't work with nested try/catches, though, so you'd need to replace the nested blocks first and then the outer blocks last.

Comment: Removing the try-catch in places where the exception is legitimately handled is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirty trick:**

1. search & replace try -> if(true) //WAS TRY
2. search & replace catch§ -> if(true) //WAS CATCH §

§ is a placeholder for the regex to match what is catched and put it after the comment WAS CATCH

by this way you can:

- revert searching WAS TRY and WAS CATCH §
- decide what has to be replaced and what has not when during rhe search

I use to comment with // DUMMY every catch that is temporary during the debug session.

*(since this is a very old post, I didn't take all the time needed to write the regex etc... please be patient)*